# Trying to delete a value in a string array does not work - Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, null

So I have a method that accepts a value from another method, and if that value exists in the relevant array, deletes it.  Debugging and stepping through I can see the string value be set to null.

For testing purposes, I'm having the method print the array straight after, so I can see if the value has been deleted correctly, which it hasn't.

```
public static String[] updateArray(String someValue) {

    for (String s : theArray) {
        if (s.contains(someValue)) {
            System.out.println(s + " This is value to be deleted");
            s = null;  // someValue is "deleted" from the array here
            System.out.println(s + " This is the value after being deleted");  //This prints the index as being "null", which it should



            break;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
for (String s2 : theArray) {  // someValue reappears in the position it was in before, when printed here, indicating that the above s=null does nothing for some reason.
        System.out.println(s2 + " -");
    }        return theArray;
}
```

Is setting the index to null where the contents match someValue wrong?  What am I missing here?

Comment: By "delete" do you just mean set the value at the index to null? Or do you want to shorten the array length? Arrays have fixed length, but it's possible if you use an `ArrayList` or a copy of the array.

Comment: Along with the solution that @Claverie gave you also need to remove your second break otherwise, you'll never continue your loop even if it doesn't match.  Just remove the else statement completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using foreach, you set the local variable `s` to null, but not the one contained in the array. You have to use a for loop for that :

```
for (int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
    if (theArray[i].contains(someValue)) {
        theArray[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was under the impression somehow that .contains() wouldn't work unless a foreach was used.  Now I know that's not the case.